# Two __VCAP_ID__ created for a single JSESSIONID

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an Authentication microservice in Pivotal cloud foundry which is built on Spring SAML2. It is integrated with PingFederate IDP. Whenever this service is invoked from a web application, a JSESSIONID is created. In order for this service to work properly, sticky session needs to be enabled. The http request for auth and the response has to be handled by the same service instance in PCF. However, it is not happening. Request is going out from one instance and response coming back to another instance. Since the response doesn't find the SAML message in current session, the authentication fails. Below is the flow -

Browser-->GoRouter for UI-->Angular UI Service and Nginx Reverse proxy-->GoRouter for API-->Auth Service-->PingFed

PCF allows to have sticky sessions based on JSESSIONID. However, when the web app tries to access Auth service through Nginx reverse proxy, there are 2 **VCAP_ID**'s created for a single JSESSIONID. Due to this, the response from PingFed is not able to reach the same auth service instance from the request went out. So, i would like to know why PCF is creating 2 __VCAP_ID's for a JSESSIONID, when the request comes through reverse proxy?

I tried different storage like redis. But, since the Spring sAML2 works on httpstorage, i was not successful. It will be like hacking the Spring Saml2 which i don't want to do.

I tried to check which app the VCAP_ID's belong to by restage the applications. I got to know that one VCAP_ID was for reverse proxy instance and the other one was for the auth service. So, the VCAP_ID for the reverse proxy is causing the issue and am not sure how to eliminate that.

Expected: PCF should create ONE VCAP_ID for a JSESSIONID per instance.

Actual: PCF creating TWO VCAP_ID's for a JSESSIONID per instance

Comment: A couple things here: 1.) "PCF" is a whole bunch of things, so when you assert it is adding the headers you need to be a lot more specific. 2.) I don't see Gorouter in your diagram and that's what would be inserting the VCAP_ID normally, can you give a more accurate description of request flow? You're going to need to drill down here and see at exactly which hop of the request flow the extra header is added. When you can pin down which hop adds the request, it'll then be possible to dig into why it's being added there.

Comment: @DanielMikusa, I have edit the flow to be specific and included GoRouter. Hope this helps.  UI service and Auth Service are different instances in PCF. Nginx reverse proxy is part of the UI instance. Additional VCAP_ID is added when the traffic flows through GoRouter for API to the Auth Service.

Comment: Is your Nginx forwarding the `JSESSIONID` & `__VCAP_ID__` cookies along to the auth service? `__VCAP_ID__` is definitely not going to be valid because that's a different app and will have it's on instance ids, and `JSESSIONID` would only be valid if you're sharing cookies across your two *different* apps. You should probably be filtering out the cookies from your frontend app in Nginx and overriding them with the same cookies names but with values that are valid on your backend app.

Comment: Yes. JSESSIONID & __VCAP_ID__ are forwarded to the auth service. But, it is picking the __VCAP_ID__ of NGINX instead of the __VCAP_ID__ of auth service. JSESSIONID is created at the auth service. But not sure why __VCAP_ID__ is being created for Nginx. Nginx is used a reverse proxy to forward all requests to backend auth service. This where i am confused and stuck.

Comment: One more challenge is, since there are 2 __VCAP_ID__'s, i am not sure which one to pick and set it in the header. Now, by default, it is picking __VCAP_ID__ for Nginx which i don't want.